# C# LINQ - Group by

Tags: c#, performance, linq

I would like to Sum grouped items. I would like to do keep simple LINQ syntax.

What I need to fix in the code to get items for key. I am trying like "g[g.Key].Count()", which doesn't work.

```
public class Order
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
}

public class Group
{
    public string GroupId { get; set; }
    public string Count { get; set; }
}     


**var groupedOrd = orders.GroupBy(f => f.Group);**
List<Group> groups = new List<Group>();
foreach(var g in groupedOrd)
{
   groups.Add(new Group() { GroupId = g.Key, Count = g[g.Key].Count() });
}
```

Comment: `which doesn't work.` what does it mean?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Group by in LINQ](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7325278/group-by-in-linq)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`GroupBy`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.groupby?view=netcore-3.1#System_Linq_Enumerable_GroupBy__2_System_Collections_Generic_IEnumerable___0__System_Func___0___1__) returns `IEnumerable` of [`IGrouping<TKey,TElement>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.igrouping-2?view=netcore-3.1) which implements `IEnumerable<T>` so you can just do `g.Count()`:

```
var groups  = groupedOrd
    .Select(g => new Group { GroupId = g.Key, Count = g.Count() } )
    .ToList();
```

Also your `Group.Count` property is a string for some reason, so you will need to change it to `int` or do `g.Count().ToString()`

Comment: Technically the result of `GroupBy` is a `IEnumerable<IGrouping<TKey, TElement>>` and `IGrouping<TKey, TElement>` is `IEnuemrable<TElement>` which is why you can do the `g.Count()`.

Comment: @juharr, yes, was adding links and signatures, thank you.